# Adding UIActivityController on the splash screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I took a **default.png** file and made it as my splash screen and i made it sleep for a few seconds to make it visible.

But i also want to add an `UIActivityController` to it.
As i didn't take any `ViewController`.

How should i add it?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

_homeViewController = [[XTHomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:kHOME_VIEW bundle:nil];
_navigate = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_homeViewController];

[self.window addSubview:_navigate.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.75];
return YES;
```

This is All i Have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Activityindicater like this

```
in DemoappeDelegate.h file

IBOutlet UiView *splashView;

in DemoappDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

   UIActivityIndicatorView *spinningWheel = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(145.0, 290.0, 25.0, 25.0)];
   [spinningWheel startAnimating];
   spinningWheel.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
   [splashView addSubview:spinningWheel];
   [spinningWheel release];
}
```

Comment: i posted my code above.i added ur code to it and its not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way using UIActivityController but you can do it following way

First of all, you take

in .h file

```
IBOutlet UIProgressView * threadProgressView;
```

in .m file

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    - (void)viewDidLoad 
    {

        threadProgressView.progress = 0.0;
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; 
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

//For progress bar 

- (void)makeMyProgressBarMoving {

    float actual = [threadProgressView progress];
    if (actual < 1) {
        threadProgressView.progress = actual + 0.02;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
```

Comment: So you want me to take another viewcontroller for a splashscreen??.Cant we do it without a new ViewController?

Comment: Are you use window based or view based application??

Comment: i am using a window based application.